# Oracle 12C: Insert script takes too much time after truncate

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

We have a production environment with Oracle 12C. It has two instances and is using Oracle Data Guard to have a replica in another server.
Every time that we release a new version, we have to truncate some tables, which doesn’t have any index, and execute several scripts with inserts statements like this one:

```
ALTER TABLE T_I18N DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
TRUNCATE TABLE T_I18N;
INSERT INTO T_I18N VALUES ('sp', 'Table 1', '0', 'Tabla 1');
INSERT INTO T_I18N VALUES ('sp', 'Table 2', '0', 'Tabla 2');
INSERT INTO T_I18N VALUES ('sp', 'Table 3', '0', 'Tabla 3');
.
.
ALTER TABLE HIS_I18N ENABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
```

Previously, we also have disabled all the primary keys and foreign keys. To give more information, the table structure is the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE "T_I18N" 
   ("T_CODE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "T_KEY" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "T_C_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "T_VALUE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "HIN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("T_CODE", "T_KEY", "T_C_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TB1"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "HIN_CEN_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("T_C_ID")
      REFERENCES "TB1"."T_CEN" ("T_C_ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "TB1";
```

The script with more Insert statements has about 20K and it takes about 12 minutes to be executed. In my opinion, it was taking too much time, so I took a different approach. I tried to drop the table, recreate it and then execute the script, and it took only 40 seconds.

I have been searching through Oracle website to understand why there are so much difference between drop/recreate and truncate, but unfortunately I couldn’t find any clue about it.

Thanks by advance. Any information or advice would be really appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: There is no universally applicable answer here. We would expect inserts into an empty table should take the same length of time regardless of how the table is empty. Probably there are some differences that you haven't told us. So, you'll need to provide way more information about your situation. For instance, is this reproducible?

Comment: Consider using the /*+APPEND*/ hint in your INSERT statements. This tells Oracle to use direct path inserts. I am not sure if this is the bottleneck though--the bottleneck might be network or SQL parsing of so many individual statements.

Comment: It could be that you are just disabling and enabling the triggers versus dropping and recreating the triggers is causing the slowdown; but 12 minutes to load 20,000 rows is too long.  You may need to enable tracing (DBMS_SESSION.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE and _DISABLE) and try both methods, (tracing each method in separate sessions) and using tkprof to see what is going on

Comment: As APC says there must be some other property of the table/index causing this. But a  couple of things to try. Add `REUSE STORAGE` when truncating. Also try flushing the shared pool, and buffer pool. Just to see if that has any effect at all.

Comment: If you can not get the performance you desire using DML, perhaps consider a direct path load using SQL Loader (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-conventional-and-direct-loads.html#GUID-A8911483-65C5-4348-886C-1C607CACA486)?

Comment: And how does the execution plan of your INSERT statements differ if you evaluate the plan immediately after table creation and again after truncating the table?

Comment: Thanks everybody! It is reproducible. Every time that I test it I have approximately the same difference of time. I was thinking to use the append hint, but the database is using Data Guard and I cannot avoid the redo. I will try to enable the trace, check the execution plan of both methods and I will check the pros and cons of flushing the shared poll and buffer pool.
About SQL Loader, is true that is a really fast tool. I have used it with a really good results in other projects. I will try it with the truncate and drop/create statements to check the difference of time between them.